# Is possible to read a value from a dynamic HTML table and pass it to an input form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm using on WordPress an amazing tablepress plugin and I have a table on one page that I want to read and pass the value of the table to an input form.
The table is the result of a search and will be always a row and a column, just one number. 
There is any way to do that with PHP or javascript?
Or any other way?

I will share some code of the result in the page...

Thanks in advance!

```
<table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1">
<tbody>
<tr class="row-1">
    <td class="column-1">319</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have jquery available...if so:

`var fromTable = $("#tablepress-1 tr td").text()` will give you the value you want.

You can do something similar to put it into your form:

`$("#myInputField").text(fromTable)`

And if you don't have jQuery, but you KNOW the tables you can get the value like this:

`var fromTable = document.getElementById("tablepress-1").rows[0].cells[0].inn‌​erText`

(Consider all of this pseudo-code and fix it up to suit your situation.  The debugger is your friend!)

Comment: If you want pure js way: document.getElementById('input').value = document.getElementsByClassName('column-1')[0].innerText

Comment: Is "input" a valid ID?  Or were you using it as a placeholder?

Comment: It is just id which i gave to the input. Default quick creation :) <input id='input'>

Comment: No jquery available... Thanks for the answer anyway but I get the concept.  I think I will need something more specific.

Comment: OK, then ... :)  `document.getElementById("tablepress-1").rows[0].cells[0].innerText`

Comment: Thank you very much ... I get the concept. Now to run it on WordPress is one other problem... :-)

Comment: Yeah - I can't help you there, unfortunately.